# What do I need to do to make be able to make some changes to proxied linked objects?

Tags: objects, linked-data

I've added an object by linking it. I've selected it and CTRL-ALT-P to make it a proxy. I can make some changes, like overall scale and position, but can't scale just one edge-loop, for example.

Also, in the original blend, the object is shaded smooth. When linked, it's flat and I can't change that either.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linked objects can only be altered in the original file, that's the point of them being proxied.

When you Link and object (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>) you can make a local copy. However this won't work unless you make your Linked Group local.

When you proxy the object <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> from a linked group <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>, it simply creates a duplicate, which change the object level properties (like Transformation, Delta Transformation, etc).
The original oject is still in the Linked Group.

[image]

If you wish to change your geometry you have to make a local **copy** by clicking the copy number in the object data section. Editing this copy will however not change the group object.

[image]

This copy could also have simply been appended to the current file <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you. I thought I had read that linking also allowed edits which would propagate back to the original, but if I understand you that was a misunderstanding.

I would mark this the answer, but if this answers my secondary question (I probably should have split it) about smooth shading not coming through, I don't see how. If you could add that then this would fully answer my question.

Comment: Whoops! I was sure it was smooth in the original, but I was mistaken. Thank you again!

Comment: @pr3sidentspence Sadly, it's a one way link.